# Unable to download skype

Tags: software-center, skype

Each time I try to install Skype from Software Center, an error about archive management or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3gd5.png) comes up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has happened a couple of times with that specific package (Still don't know why). I would recommend going to the [Skype Download](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64) page for the Ubuntu package and you can install it from there on.

For what I can tell it has problems with some libraries depending on the arch type (32 Bit or 64 Bit). But the package in the Skype Download side works correctly for both.